# New ubuntu 20.04 install, zfs on root -- root and boot filling up

Tags: zfs

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04 for zfs boot+root purposes.

Every morning I've come to the workstation, it's exceedingly slow and unstable, and shows zero bytes free for / .

Snapshots completely fill the drive. It's a 256GB NVMe SSD. It's small, I know -- but is that normal?

I need to run:

```
zsysctl service gc -a
```

to free up a bit of space to use as normal. In addition, that didn't remove any snapshots today. I had to pick a snapshot and manually destroy it to get a few GB free.

Am I missing something?

Edit: sudo parted -l output:

```
Model: PM951 NVMe SAMSUNG 256GB (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32           EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   2685MB  2147MB  linux-swap(v1)                        swap
 3      2685MB  4833MB  2147MB  zfs
 4      4833MB  256GB   251GB   zfs
```

Further, I'm using sanoid now. No unnecessary filling of any partitions.

Comment: Most likely you have wrong partitions. What does `sudo parted -l` output?

Comment: Please don't post infromation to comments. [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Kill zsys with fire. Disable it completely and purge all of it's snapshots. It's existence is a terrible manifestation of "not invented here" mentality.

Use sanoid instead. It is far more mature, easy to configure, and will take care of your snapshots and pruning them, and can be easily instructed to not take more snapshots if your free disk space drops below a certain threshold.

Comment: I don't disagree. I love me some sanoid. Commencing death to zsys now...